# Craft Commerce - explain transaction types and statuses to me

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Commerce transactions have multiple possible types and statuses:

```
    const TYPE_AUTHORIZE = 'authorize';
    const TYPE_CAPTURE = 'capture';
    const TYPE_PURCHASE = 'purchase';
    const TYPE_REFUND = 'refund';

    const STATUS_PENDING = 'pending';
    const STATUS_REDIRECT = 'redirect';
    const STATUS_PROCESSING = 'processing';
    const STATUS_SUCCESS = 'success';
    const STATUS_FAILED = 'failed';
```

Can someone explain to me what each of them means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transaction can have a single type and status at one time.
A transaction can also have a parent transaction relationship.

**There are 4 transaction types:**
`authorize`, `capture`, `purchase`, `refund`.

A transaction type determines what the transactions is and how it is counted when determining the order totals.

`authorize` is used when the customer is not immediately charged to their card, but an authorization is placed on their card. The authorization will be captured at a later time, and the customers card will then be charged. An authorization can have the status of `pending`, `redirect`, `processing`, `success`, or `failed`.

`capture` transactions are always child transactions of `authorize` transactions. You can only capture a `authorize` transaction that had a `success` status. A capture can have the status of `success`, or `failed`.

`purchase` is used when the customer is getting charged immediately to their card. An purchase can have the status of `pending`, `redirect`, `processing`, `success`, or `failed`.

`refund` is used when the customer was refunded an amount. It can only be the child of a `capture` or `purchase` transactions that have the status of `success`

**There are 5 transaction statuses:**
`pending`, `redirect`, `processing`, `success`, `failed`.

`pending` status is for when a transaction is first created. It could then be changed to different status once the gateway/customer determines what the transaction should be. For example, changed to the `redirect` status when the customer is being redirected off-site.

`redirect` status us when the customer was sent off-site. A redirect status should only be used for `authorized` and `capture` transactions as capture and refunds are usually done by an admin from the control panel and not taken off-site to perform those actions.

`processing` is a semi-successful status introduced due to asynchronous nature of some gateways where knowing if the transaction is successful or failed will happen at a later time. For example, in stripe the customer might be returned from a SCA offsite back to the craft site and we will update the transaction as `processing` before the webhook comes in with the results of the payment from the bank. When we get a `processing` status on an `authorize` or `purchase` transaction we still
'complete' the cart and turn it into an order. So the only way for a customer to complete a cart is to have a successful purchase or authorization or a successful processing transaction.

`success` status means the transaction was successful. This covers the `authorization`, `capture`, `purchase` and `refund`.

`failed` status means the transaction failed. This covers `authorization`, `capture`, `purchase` and `refund`.

We will update the docs with the above.

Comment: Very comprehensive, thanks! Can you also write about concept of "child transactions" a bit?

Comment: Great to see this spelled out.  

Perhaps be worth explaining how 'capture' can be used just a tad more for non credit card contexts - e.g. we 'capture' a payment once it is visible in our bank account.  This then means the order becomes available for our module to push to our external inventory system.